# gawk with gawkextlib

Tags: awk, gawk

In my system (Slackware64-14.1) `gawk` is installed in version 4.1.0.  I'd like to install [gawkextlib](http://gawkextlib.sourceforge.net) to have access to some of its features, namely `xml`.

From the `README` file of `gawkextlib-0.4.9`:

> To use this library, you must first build the new version of gawk
>   containing shared extension library support.  Please use gawk 4.1 or
>   later, or use this recipe to build from the git sources:
>
> git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/gawk.git    cd gawk
>   ./bootstrap.sh    ./configure --prefix=/tmp/newgawk    make && make
>   check && make install
>
> After you build and install that in /tmp/newgawk, you can then build
>   gawkextlib like so:
>
> Using git:    git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/gawkextlib/code
>   gawkextlib    cd gawkextlib    ./update-autotools
>
> Or it may be easier from a tarball if you do not have current
>   autotools installed:    tar xf gawkextlib-.tar.gz    cd
>   gawkextlib-
>
> Either way, the steps to build are the same:    ./configure
>   --with-gawk=/tmp/newgawk --prefix=/tmp/newgawk    make && make check && make install

The process fails with:

> /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/tmp/newgawk/lib/gawk'  /bin/sh ../libtool
>   --mode=install ../build-aux/install-sh -c   xml.la gd.la mpfr.la '/tmp/newgawk/lib/gawk' libtool: install: error: cannot install
>   `xml.la' to a directory not ending in /usr/lib/gawk make[2]: ***
>   [install-pkgextensionLTLIBRARIES] Error 1

This is not a big problem, as I'd really like `gawkextlib` to integrate with existing `gawk` residing in `/usr`.  So, when:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-gawk=/usr
$ make && make test 
# make install
```

Everything installs fine.

```
# ls /usr/lib/libgawkextlib.*
/usr/lib/libgawkextlib.la  /usr/lib/libgawkextlib.so  /usr/lib/libgawkextlib.so.0  /usr/lib/libgawkextlib.so.0.0.0
```

but

```
$ awk -l xml
awk: fatal: can't open shared library `xml' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

From `gawk` man page:

> -l
>
> --load lib Load a shared library lib.  This searches for the library using the AWKLIBPATH  environment  variable.   If  the initial  search
>   fails,  another  attempt will be made after appending the default
>   shared library suffix for the platform.  The library initialization
>   routine is expected to be named dl_load().

After setting up `AWKLIBPATH`:

```
$ export AWKLIBPATH=/usr/lib
$ echo $AWKLIBPATH          
/usr/lib
$ awk -l xml
awk: fatal: can't open shared library `xml' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

`awk` aka `gawk` can't find the shared library.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you get that error when you use `gawk` as well or only with `awk`?

Comment: @terdon: `$ ll *awk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4 Nov  9 22:58 awk -> gawk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov  9 22:58 gawk -> gawk-4.1.0`  so `awk` == `gawk` in my system.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just wondering if invoking it as `awk` causes it to run in compatibility mode, as though run with `--posix`. I have no idea if this is the case, but you may as well try it with `gawk` just on the off chance. Both `bash` and `gksudo` change their behavior depending on which name you use to invoke them, there may be something similar for `gawk`.

Comment: I don't think it's a path problem, I followed the same basic procedure and get a more informative error: `gawk: fatal: load_ext: cannot open library '/usr/local/lib/gawk/xml.so' (libgawkextlib.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)` but `/usr/local/lib/gawk/xml.so` exists and is readable.

Comment: I had the same problem installing `pgsql` (and `gawkextlib`) to a private path. Setting `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mypath/lib` (where `libgawkextlib.so.0` exists) solved the problem. I verified this with `strace /mypath/bin/gawk '@load "pgsql"'`. This was in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there were no answers, I asked in the `gawkextlib` mailing list about this problem.  One of the authors of the project, Andrew Schorr, suggested that one could use the following command:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --sysconfdir=/etc --datadir=/usr/share --includedir=/usr/include --libdir=/usr/lib64 --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --localstatedir=/var --sharedstatedir=/var/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info
```

As there were some superfluous options, I stripped it down to:

```
./configure  --datadir=/usr/share  --libdir=/usr/lib64
```

And `gawkextlib` installs fine and is usable with `gawk`.
One can also add the option `--prefix=/usr` to have `xmlgawk` script installed in `/usr/bin` instead of `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this issue, and James Brown's comment really helped.  I had to add the following environment variables:

```
export AWKLIBPATH=/usr/local/lib/gawk/   # path where xml.so exists
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/   # path where libgawkextlib.so.0 exists
```

But I think the answer from Luis is better in the long run.  According to [The Linux Documentation Project](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html): "LD_LIBRARY_PATH is handy for development and testing, but shouldn't be modified by an installation process for normal use by normal users"