# How to install gawk-csv (and gawkextlib)?

Tags: software-installation, csv, gawk, plugin

There are simple and objective way to install the [CSV extension for `gawk`](http://gawkextlib.sourceforge.net/csv/gawk-csv.html#Installing-the-CSV-extension)?

---

### Try and stop.. need for more one step

Using UBUNTU 18 LTS.

1. `wget -c  http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gawk/gawk-5.0.1.tar.gz` (and `gawk-5.0.1.tar.gz.sig`)
2. `gpg --verify gawk-5.0.1.tar.gz.sig   gawk-5.0.1.tar.gz` 
   ERROR: "using RSA key DF597815937EC0D2... Can't check signature: No public key".
3. `tar xvzf    gawk-5.0.1.tar.gz`
4. `cd gawk-5.0.1`
5. after `sudo su` run `./configure && make && make check && make install`

```
...
... long long process
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib/gawk

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the '-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the '-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to '/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
make  install-data-hook
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/extension'
for i in filefuncs.la fnmatch.la fork.la inplace.la intdiv.la ordchr.la readdir.la readfile.la revoutput.la revtwoway.la rwarray.la time.la ; do \
        rm -f /usr/local/lib/gawk/$i ; \
done
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/extension'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/extension'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/extension'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/extension'
Making install in extras
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/extras'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/extras'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/etc/profile.d'
 .././install-sh -c -m 644 gawk.sh gawk.csh '/usr/local/etc/profile.d'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/extras'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/extras'
Making install in doc
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/doc'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/doc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/info'
 .././install-sh -c -m 644 ./gawk.info ./gawkinet.info ./gawkworkflow.info '/usr/local/share/info'
 install-info --info-dir='/usr/local/share/info' '/usr/local/share/info/gawk.info'
 install-info --info-dir='/usr/local/share/info' '/usr/local/share/info/gawkinet.info'
 install-info --info-dir='/usr/local/share/info' '/usr/local/share/info/gawkworkflow.info'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/man/man1'
 .././install-sh -c -m 644 gawk.1 '/usr/local/share/man/man1'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/doc'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/doc'
Making install in awklib
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/awklib'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/awklib'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/libexec/awk'
  .././install-sh -c pwcat grcat '/usr/local/libexec/awk'
make  install-exec-hook
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/awklib'
/bin/bash ../mkinstalldirs /usr/local/share/awk
mkdir -p -- /usr/local/share/awk
for i in passwd.awk group.awk ./eg/lib/*.awk ; do \
        progname=`echo $i | sed 's;.*/;;'` ; \
        .././install-sh -c -m 644 $i /usr/local/share/awk/$progname ; \
done
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/awklib'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/awklib'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/awklib'
Making install in po
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/po'
installing ca.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES/gawk.mo
installing da.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/gawk.mo
installing de.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/gawk.mo
installing es.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/gawk.mo
installing fi.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES/gawk.mo
installing fr.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/gawk.mo
installing id.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/gawk.mo
installing it.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/gawk.mo
installing ja.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/gawk.mo
installing ko.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES/gawk.mo
installing ms.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/ms/LC_MESSAGES/gawk.mo
installing nl.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/gawk.mo
installing pl.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/gawk.mo
installing pt.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/pt/LC_MESSAGES/gawk.mo
installing pt_BR.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/gawk.mo
installing sv.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/gawk.mo
installing vi.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES/gawk.mo
installing zh_CN.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/gawk.mo
if test "gawk" = "gettext-tools"; then \
  /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/share/gettext/po; \
  for file in Makefile.in.in remove-potcdate.sin quot.sed boldquot.sed en@quot.header en@boldquot.header insert-header.sin Rules-quot   Makevars.template; do \
    .././install-sh -c -m 644 ./$file \
                    /usr/local/share/gettext/po/$file; \
  done; \
  for file in Makevars; do \
    rm -f /usr/local/share/gettext/po/$file; \
  done; \
else \
  : ; \
fi
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/po'
Making install in test
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/test'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/test'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/test'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/test'
```

Seems that is OK. My test `gawk --version` was 4.1.1 now is 5.0.1. 
In the dump above we can see `make[4]: Entering directory '/home/admin_dq/transfer/AWK/gawk-5.0.1/extension'`, so seems the extension-lib is there.

But now the original problem: I need `gawk-csv`  and it is "command not found".

How to download and **install CSV extension?**

I try also `gawk -i csv`  but error *"gawk: fatal: can't open source file `csv' for reading (No such file or directory)"*.

PS1: how to check the list all extensions installed? 
PS2: [another guide](http://gawkextlib.sourceforge.net/README.pdf) say that I need to run `rpmbuild`...

---

### Notes

Summary:  I need the tool, not to learn about hacking.

Seems that the Linux name of the tool is `gawk-csv`, but the name of its main lib is `gawkextlib`.

There are two conflicting guides, [README](http://gawkextlib.sourceforge.net/README.html) and [Installing-the-CSV-extension](http://gawkextlib.sourceforge.net/csv/gawk-csv.html#Installing-the-CSV-extension). The only download is provided for the first.

PS: there are [6 years old queestion here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/102976/130402), but only now 2020 the `gawk-csv` is version 1.0.0.

### CSV is important

It is a very important extension for [classic AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK), because generic CSV file is not only "`a,b,c`", AWK need to parse [standard CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) quotations, escaped lines, etc.

AWK is perfect (!),  but it is **impossible to do [simple ETL tasks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) of big CSV files** with classic AWK, we need *gawk-csv*.

Comment: Try removing the dot at the end? `make install` not `make install.`.

Comment: Hi @mosvy, all again (`./configure && make && make check && make install`) or only the last command? Not need `sudo`?

Comment: You don't need sudo or install in your system directories (they should be under the control of the distro, period). Simply `./configure --prefix=/some/path && make install` and then use `/some/path/bin/awk`. Then you should do the same with gawkextlib and the csv extension. That's pretty involved and there are a thousand way that could fail (lack of development packages, etc). Frankly, I don't see the point of it -- the csv format is no big deal, after all.

Comment: And I'm not sure that you have to build gawk from source at all.

Comment: @mosvy (seems not you) or any other, please **comment your downvoting**.

Comment: Except for newlines inside quoted fields, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60676023/10306503) may do (with gawk). And even newlines inside quoted fields may be done, with a little bit of sorcery. The whole csv [standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) is ~5 pages, including 4 of adminstrative boilerplate ;-)

Comment: I do not vote -- I'm using a firefox extension (kind of a userscript) which won't let me, even if I would ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This recipe worked for me right now. YMMV.

Change `DSTPATH` to wherever you want to install that extension.

I do NOT recommend ever installing *anything at all* by hand in the system directories (eg. under `/usr`); that should only be managed by the distro's tools (`apt`, `yum`, etc).

```
DSTPATH=/tmp/baz
set -e
git clone https://git.code.sf.net/p/gawkextlib/code gawkextlib-code
cd gawkextlib-code/lib
autoreconf -i
./configure --prefix=$DSTPATH && make -j13 install
cd ../csv
autoreconf -i
./configure --prefix=$DSTPATH --with-gawkextlib=$DSTPATH && make -j13 install

export AWKPATH=$DSTPATH/share/awk AWKLIBPATH=$DSTPATH/lib/gawk
echo foo,bar,baz | gawk -i csv 'csvsplit($0,a){print a[2]}'
```

This is all overkill IMHO, and there are a thousand ways it may fail (lack of proper development tools, etc).

Comment: git ok. I installed `apt install autoconf`.. again cd `gawkextlib-code/lib`  and  `autoreconf -i`  but "autom4te: cannot create autom4te.cache: No such file or directory" .. after `sudo autoreconf -i` and some messages like "configure.ac:14: installing 'build-aux/ar-lib'" shows error, *"Makefile.am:7: error: Libtool library used but 'LIBTOOL' is undefined" ... "autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1"*... Seems insane....

Comment: You don't need sudo at all for that. You do need `libtool`, `autoconf`, `automake`, development packages, compilers, etc. I won't turn this answer into a tutorial on how to set a complete development platform, sorry.

Comment: Thanks @mosvy, I really need AWK-CSV (see  "CSV is important" section) but is insane to use a tool that is not ready to final ordinary users... I will stop to try (my server UBUNTU 18 LTS is fresh and perfect, and will be in risk ... the problem is with the installation that must be simple `apt`).

Comment: @PeterKrauss if you want a CSV-capable text processing tool that can be installed in Ubuntu, try `miller`. Alternatively there is the python-based `csvkit`. Or you can use Python itself, or Perl (with the Text::CSV module provided by package `libtext-csv-perl`). All work out-of-the-box with no compiling required.

Comment: The last line looks stupid.

Comment: @jarno OK, I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the debate about installing to /usr to one side - The main problem I found with building the csv library is that the Makefile does not specify the **runtime** path required for locating gawkextlib when linking the `csv.so` library.  This means that without setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `csv.so` will not find `libgawkextlib.so.0` at runtime, even tho the build and install will appear successful.  The result is an error like this on invoking gawk:

```
gawk: csv:15: fatal: load_ext: cannot open library `/usr/local/lib/gawk/csv.so' (libgawkextlib.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

gawk is finding `csv.so` under `/usr/local/lib/gawk/csv.so`, but `csv.so` then depends on `libgawkextlib.so.0` which is not on the runtime library path.

I couldn't find an option in `configure` to resolve this and ended up running the link line from the make output again, but adding the following:
`-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib`

`-Wl` sends the following options directly to the link from `gcc`.

So the full line is:
`gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/csv.o .libs/csv_parser.o .libs/csv_convert.o .libs/csv_split.o .libs/csv_input.o .libs/strbuf.o .libs/awk_fieldwidth_info.o   -L/usr/local/lib/ -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/bin -lgawkextlib  -g -O2   -Wl,-soname -Wl,csv.so -o .libs/csv.so`

After this `csv.so` could find `libgawkextlib.so.0` without me manupulating the library search path:

```
$ ldd csv.so 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffda36e6000)
        libgawkextlib.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libgawkextlib.so.0 (0x00007ffb8f535000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffb8f144000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ffb8f93d000)
```

So total procedure for me on Ubuntu 18.04, was as follows, using a version of gawk previously build from source and installed at `/usr/local/bin/gawk`.  Also note I had all the build tools installed already, you may need to use `apt` to install the likes of gcc, autoconf, libtool, etc - a good starting point is `sudo apt install build-essential`.

Get Source:

```
git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/gawkextlib/code gawkextlib
cd gawkextlib
```

Build lib - nothing special here - `with-gawk` just ensures we use our compiled version of gawk, not the system version:

```
cd lib
autoreconf -i
./configure --with-gawk=/usr/local/bin/
make
sudo make install
```

Build csv extension with patch to library:

```
cd ../csv
autoreconf -i
./configure --with-gawk=/usr/local/bin/ --with-gawkextlib=/usr/local/lib/
make
gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/csv.o .libs/csv_parser.o .libs/csv_convert.o .libs/csv_split.o .libs/csv_input.o .libs/strbuf.o .libs/awk_fieldwidth_info.o   -L/usr/local/lib/ -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/bin -lgawkextlib  -g -O2   -Wl,-soname -Wl,csv.so -o .libs/csv.so
sudo make install
```

Success:

```
$ echo foo,bar,baz | gawk -i csv 'csvsplit($0,a){print a[2]}'
bar
```

Last hint - if you have issues with `makeinfo` not being installed - on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install texinfo
```